# Maintenance/Upgrades for Gary Fisher Joshua MTB

Tags: maintenance, repair, gears

Let me start from the beginning:

About three years ago, I broke my leg after buying a Gary Fisher Joshua MTB, when I was just getting into road and cross-country riding. I've only started riding again recently, and the chain is slipping etc and the gear selector won't go into the top cog on the rear. It's my own fault for leaving it static and not at least having it serviced whilst it was in my garage. So I've decided to rip the drivetrain apart and start again.

**Question:** Can someone help be identify what gear shifters to buy, as well as how to replace the front cogs (3 cogs & crank, rear 8 cogs), derailer and rear mechanical bits, and obviously the chain?

I like the look and feel of the Shimano Alivio components, would those be good for this kind of riding?

(Future work: I will probably change the front shocks and rear suspension bit as well as new handle bars and grips/barends too. The wheels and tyres are pretty much brand new, have only ridden about 150 miles.)

---

[image]
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Also, the reason for changing is that it all looks a bit naff. The two silver tubes at the top of the shox are corrording also, so will probably get a new front end also.

I need help on the front derailer, and rear mech if possible.  I have ordered a new rear cassette (Shimano HG31 11 30T) and new crank and chainset (Shimano Alivio MTB 42T 170 BLK) and Shimano shifters (St-M410 Aliio STI).  I'm looking at Shimano Deore V-Brakes also as the ones on the bike are starting to corrode. This ia all my own fault for not looking after the bike when I was off.

I need some advice on front/rear shocks - handlebars etc.

Also, it may sound stupid, but where can I get the bikes bolts from?  As the ones on are proper rusty and look a mess!

Comment: If you haven't got rid of the parts you plan to remove from the bike, my advice would be: don't! Usually, bicycle part, specially the metal ones, don't spoil even if you don't use them in decades. Most probably just a service, perhaps done in a bike shop, would let your bike feeling as new. It might be necessary to replace tires and tubes, too.

Comment: @heltonbiker - See my rewrite, I *think* this question is fine now.

Comment: Grant, welcome to Bicycles! I've taken the liberty of rewriting your question so it's more targeted and readable. Also, since you asked about this in your original question, I've changed "gears" to "drivetrain" and so on. Please feel free to further edit what I've done in case I've missed the point somewhere, or inadvertently removed something of vital importance. (FYI, we tend to avoid salutations in questions, and people here are *very* good about helping newbies without being patronizing.)

Comment: Please post photos of the bike and details of its original specifications. It will help us help you right. Thanks.

Comment: @zenbike - Yes, pictures. Although I'm a little leery of seeing a cool bike like this pulled to pieces...

Comment: Have a shop clean & tune it a bit, then ride it for awhile.  There's some superficial corrosion, but nothing that will make the bike unusable, and after riding a month or three you'll get a feel for what really needs replacing and what doesn't.

Comment: (The bolts should be stainless steel, and will clean up with a bit of steel wool polishing.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is in line with heltonbikers.Bring the bike to a local shop and have them look at it.A simple tune-up may be all that is needed.Many shops offer spring specials so call early to avoid delays.I am not sure why you assume you need to replace all these parts .My theory on upgrades is to wait until there is a need to replace a component.If a parts is functioning and meeting your needs why replace it?My guess is that if both were properly adjusted most people couldn't tell the difference between the alivio and deore line.If your shifters are beyond repair that is the time to upgrade.My fisher marlin disc came with alivio and I think they're a great shifter.They are 4 years old and still work great.

Comment: Right so below are the pictures Ive just taken?  Apologies if they are not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the rapid responses.   OK here goes, please, correct me if im wrong about any info i give.

Ok, it currently has:

a CSC42R Crank - shimano
shimano 30 11 cassette.

it is a 24 speed bike  with shimano thumb touch shifters.  I'm not really sure what other info you require, point me in the right direction if you want.

I really am sorry im not much help, im kind of embarassed to be honest.  A fish completely out of water!

Ill get some pics tomorrow so hopefully you can 'see' what info you need.  is there any particular pictures that would help significantly.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses, again very greatful.